# Cannot access google map in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page in which i have several links that should open jquery-ui dialogs with google maps. Since i'm loading coordinates from wordpress custom fields, I'm outputting the coordinates in data-rel attributes so I can pick them up with jQuery. Everything works, maps get initialized, but I cannot attach a listener to a map object in maps array.

I'm doing it like this

HTML:

```
<div class="mapalokacija">
    <a title="Gde se nalazimo?" rel="addon-map-<?php echo $counter;?>" class="showmap" data-rel-lat='<?php echo $lat;?>' data-rel-long='<?php echo $long;?>' href='#map-<?php echo $counter;?>'>map</a> 
<div class="modal" id="map-<?php echo $counter;?>">
<div id="addon-map-<?php echo $counter++;?>" style="width:400;height:400px;margin:10px auto;"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var title = '<?php the_title();?>';
window.maps = new Array();

$(document).ready(function(){

    var cdc = 0;
    $('.showmap').each(function(){


        var popup = $(this).attr('href');
        var lt = $(this).attr('data-rel-lat');
        var ll = $(this).attr('data-rel-long');
        var dv = $(this).attr('rel');
        console.log(popup,lt,ll,dv,cdc);
        cdc++;
        addonMap(lt,ll,dv);


    });
});
$(window).load(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $('.showmap').each(function(){


        $('.modal').dialog({
            title: 'Gde se nalazimo?',
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            resizeStop: function(event, ui) {google.maps.event.trigger(window.maps[counter], 'resize')  },
            open: function(event, ui) {google.maps.event.trigger(window.maps[counter], 'resize');} 

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener( maps[counter], 'idle', function (){ google.maps.event.trigger(window.maps[counter],'resize');});
        counter++;

    });
});


function addonMap(lat,lng,div,ccc) {

    var lat = parseFloat(lat);
    var lng = parseFloat(lng);

    var latLang = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

    var mapOptions =    {
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        draggable: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };



    var mapstring = div;
    var lmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapstring),mapOptions);          

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLang,
        map: lmap,
        title: title
    });

    window.maps.push(lmap);


}   


$('.showmap').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var popup = $(this).attr('href');
    var lt = $(this).attr('data-rel-lat');
    var ll = $(this).attr('data-rel-long');
    var cc = $(popup).attr('rel');
    cc = +cc;
    console.log(cc);
    $(popup).dialog('open');
    google.maps.event.trigger(maps[cc], 'resize');


});
```

Live example:

[One map](http://www.firmesrbije.com/usluge/sudski-tumaci-prevodioci/3854/sudski-tumac-prevodilac-za-engleski-jezik-beograd/)
[Multiple Maps](http://www.firmesrbije.com/deca/decija-obuca/5695/decija-obuca-baldino/)

Comment: Why are you wanting to listen to the `idle` event?

Comment: So I can resize my map inside the div

Comment: give a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at your live examples and you have several errors in your code, but mainly the reason your maps don't resize is beacuse your css are not well defined and you're not focusing in the event your have to listen and in wich you have to trigger the `resize` event of the map.

To do so you have to trigger the `resize` event of the map in the `open` event of the `dialog` object.

Listen to the `idle` event of the map to trigger the `resize` event won't work as `idle` event: *is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.* As you can see here [Google Maps API Reference/Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).
So the `idle` event is not fired when the map is *ready*.

For simplicity you can consider using only one dialog and one map and bind the marker, polyline, infoWindow... your want to show as the dialog opens.

Consider the following workable example and consider also the logic that is a bit simpler and eaiser to implement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multiple Maps on Popup demo </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDYeeEtBV1zi5IOTKYz4WBD2UO0U3fuVcg&sensor=false"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI js -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        .map-container { height: 100%; width: 100%; min-width: 500px; min-height: 300px; }
        .dialog {}
        .btn-dialog{}
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <!-- buttons conveniently named as 'btn-dialog-n' where 'n' is the index of the dialog the button will open -->
            <button id="btn-dialog-0" class="btn-dialog">Open Dialog 0</button>
            <button id="btn-dialog-1" class="btn-dialog">Open Dialog 1</button>
            <button id="btn-dialog-2" class="btn-dialog">Open Dialog 2</button>
            <button id="btn-dialog-3" class="btn-dialog">Open Dialog 3</button>
            <button id="btn-dialog-4" class="btn-dialog">Open Dialog 4</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- divs (being dialogs) conveniently named as 'dialog-n' where 'n' is the index of the dialog -->
            <div id="dialog-0" class="dialog">
                <div id="map-container-0" class="map-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dialog-1" class="dialog">
                <div id="map-container-1" class="map-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dialog-2" class="dialog">
                <div id="map-container-2" class="map-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dialog-3" class="dialog">
                <div id="map-container-3" class="map-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dialog-4" class="dialog">
                <div id="map-container-4" class="map-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script language="javascript">
            // maps array --> does not have to be direcly declared as window.maps as it will 'put itself' in the global object (aka window)
            var maps = [];

            // you can do all what you was wanting to do in only this DOM ready handler event.
            $(document).ready(function() {

                //Google Maps
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                // initialize the maps and store them in 'maps' array
                $(".map-container").each(function(){
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(this, mapOptions);
                    maps.push(map);
                });


                // Dialogs
                // initialize the dialogs
                $(".dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 500,
                    width: 700,
                    modal: true,
                    open: function () {
                        // get the current dialog being opend and then get the 'id' attribut that has a simply convetion 'dialog-n' where 'n' is the index of the dialog
                        var $this = $(this),
                            index = $this.attr("id").split('-')[1];
                        // so that i can trigger the 'resize' event in the correct 'map' object
                        google.maps.event.trigger(maps[index], "resize");
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        console.log("close");
                    }
                });

                // initialize the buttons
                $(".btn-dialog").button()
                    // bind the click event to each button
                    .click(function () {
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log($(this));
                        // get the current 'button' which the user is clicking to, 
                        var $this = $(this),
                            // then get the 'id' attribute that has a simply convention 'btn-dialog-n' where 'n' is the index of the dialog the button will open
                            index = $this.attr("id").split('-')[2];
                        // then I can open the correct dialog
                        $("#dialog-" + index).dialog("open");
                    });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't believe it was this "simple" :)
Thank you very much for your help. I'll implement your code and I'll see how it goes with markers. 

Thanks again

Comment: Can I ask you to take a look on the multiple page again?
It works as it should, I just wonder is it efficient or could it be better? :)

Comment: Well, I tell you in my answer that you might consider having only one map and one dialog popup along with an array of the markers (positions) you want to show and bind the correct marker as you open the dialog. 
Things can always be better, the thing is: it is constly efficient? You could spend more time in you page but it have a cost that, maybe, won't be matched by benefits your bring to yours users.
A last recomendation for your futures developements: It is a good practice to put the JavaScript code in external .js files, that structure your code and make maintenance easier.

Comment: OK, will further optimize. 
Thanks again :)